# C reading binary files

Tags: c, file, binaryfiles

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>    [“while( !feof( file ) )” is always wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

If I write an array to the output file and I close the file, then open the file again and read everything until end-of-file is reached, although the file contains only 4 number, the program will read and print 5 numbers, why?

Program output:

```
a[0] = 4
a[1] = 7
a[2] = 12
a[3] = 34
a[4] = 34
```

save.bin (with a hex editor)

```
04000000 07000000 0C000000 22000000
```

---

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define path "save.bin"

int main(void)
{
  FILE *f=NULL;
  int a[]={4,7,12,34},i,n=4,k;
  f=fopen(path,"wb");
  if(f==NULL)
  {
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
  }
  for(i=0;i<n;i++)  // or I could use fwrite(a,sizeof(int),n,f);
    fwrite(&a[i],sizeof(int),1,f);
  fclose(f);
  f=fopen(path,"rb");
  if(f==NULL)
  {
    perror("Error");
    exit(1);
  }
  i=0;
  while(!feof(f))
  {
    fread(&k,sizeof(int),1,f);
    printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i,k);
    i++;
  }
  printf("\n");
  fclose(f);
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`feof(fp)` becomes false (i.e. non-zero value) only if you tried to *read past* the end of file. That should explain why the loop is entered one more than what you expect.

From the [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/feof.3.html):

```
  The function feof() tests the end-of-file indicator for the stream
  pointed to by stream, returning nonzero if it is set.  The end-of-
  file indicator can be cleared only by the function clearerr().
```

Also read the post: [Why is “while ( !feof (file) )” always wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5431941/while-feof-file-is-always-wrong)

Comment: +1 for explaining how `feof()` is set.

Answer (score 1):

```
while(!feof(f))
{
    fread(&k,sizeof(int),1,f);
    printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i,k);  /** THIS ASSUMES fread() WAS SUCCESSFUL. **/
    i++;
}
```

Check for end of file immedately after the call to `fread()` or check the return value of `fread()`, which returns the number of items read which in this case should be `1`. A possible restructuring of the loop:

```
while(1 == fread(&k,sizeof(int),1,f))
{
    printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i,k);
    i++;
}
```

After the loop check `feof()` to ensure EOF was reached and loop did not end due to some other failure.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem as well. Try this instead:

```
i=0;
  while(true)
  {
    fread(&k,sizeof(int),1,f);
    if(feof(f))
        break;

    printf("a[%d] = %d\n",i,k);
    i++;
  }
```

Apparently feof doesnt return true unless you've read past the end of the file. What i do when writing arrays to binary files is to write the size first, so i know the exact amount of data i'm about to read when reading it back.